# Get id value from multiple class

Tags: javascript, html, class

Is it possible to get id value from some same classes ? this is my clear.html

```
<p class="number" id="1">Number 1</p>
<p class="number" id="2">Number 2</p>
<p class="number" id="3">Number 3</p>
```

and here is clear.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var curLoadProv = document.querySelector('.number').id;
    console.log(curLoadProv)
});
```

but it just print `1` , how can I print the `2` and `3`?

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`. You'll get a nodelist containing all the elements that you can loop through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to print them separately, use [**each**](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
$('.number').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="number" id="1">Number 1</p>
<p class="number" id="2">Number 2</p>
<p class="number" id="3">Number 3</p>
```

If you want them in an array, use [**map**](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

```js
var ids = $('.number').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('id');
}).get();

console.log(ids);
console.log(ids.join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="number" id="1">Number 1</p>
<p class="number" id="2">Number 2</p>
<p class="number" id="3">Number 3</p>
```

Comment: Why not simple `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`?

Comment: @Satpal, either way works. I think it comes down to a matter of preference

Comment: You should get the native array from jQuery collection with `.get()`.

Comment: @VisioN, my oversight. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3):

Non jQuery answer:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
  Array.protoype.forEach.call(numbers, function(number) {
    console.log(number);
  });
}, false);
```

Comment: It doesn't display elements' IDs though.

Comment: True, it displays the whole element. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will return an array with IDs of all elements with class `.number`:

```
$('.number').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();  // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

The following code will iterate all elements with class `.number` and output their IDs to the console:

```
$('.number').each(function() {
    console.log( this.id );
});
```

```js
$('#first').text(
  $('.number').map(function() { return this.id; }).get()
);

$('.number').each(function() {
  $('#second').append(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="number" id="1">Number 1</p>
<p class="number" id="2">Number 2</p>
<p class="number" id="3">Number 3</p>

<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `document.querySelector()` will return only the first element satisfying the given selector.

Since you seems to be using jquery, use jQuery with class selector to fetch all the elements with the class number and then iterate over it using .each() and log the id of each elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.number').each(function() {
    snippet.log(this.id)
  })
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="number" id="1">Number 1</p>
<p class="number" id="2">Number 2</p>
<p class="number" id="3">Number 3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get values based on id

var value=document.getElementById("id").innerhtml;

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".number").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
    for(var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++){
          console.log(elements[i].id);
    }
});
```